# Exclude files from test

Tags: javascript, regex, karma-jasmine

I'm using a code for requiring all src files except main.js for coverage.
What I need is to add one more file to ignore, or ignore all files that have this extension.

```
const srcContext = require.context('../../src/renderer', true, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/)
```

This is what I'm using,
I need to also exclude *_icons.scss* or exclude all *.scss* from coverage.
I tried implementing some new regex but it does not work as expected

Thanks!

Comment: Try `/^\.\/(?!(?:main(\.js)?|.*\.scss)$)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following updated pattern:

```
/^\.\/(?!(?:main(\.js)?|.*\.scss)$)/
         ^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The main point here is to add an *alternative* to the part that matches the file names after `./`.

**Full pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\.\/` - a literal `./` substring
- `(?!(?:main(\.js)?|.*\.scss)$)` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if the following patterns match:

  - `(?:main(\.js)?|.*\.scss)` - either `main` or `main.js` substrings (at the end of the string)
  - `|` - or
  - `.*\.scss` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) up to the last `.scss` substring that is at...
  - `$` - the end of the string.